# How to resolve [1]+ Exit 1 error?

Tags: linux, error-handling, exit

I want to run four different R codes on linux batch using the following command:

```
nohup R CMD BATCH code_name.R&
```

I could run 2 of the codes on background, but running the other two codes, I get the below error

```
[1]+  Exit 1
```

The following is the R error I get:

```
[1] "03012017000000"
Error in if (difftime_last >= 0) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Execution halted
```

Would you lead me why this happens, and how I can resolve it please?

Comment: Yse, thanks for reminding, I editted that one.

Comment: We probably need to see the error messages output by R in order to help.

Comment: I adde that one as well

Comment: Run *one* instance in the foreground and debug it, before running it in the background.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing code, but does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed

Answer (score 2):

```
[1]+  Exit 1
```

...means the first background job you started (`[1]`) has just terminated with exit code 1.

Typically exit code 0 means "no error", and any non-zero exit code means some kind of an error situation: without any error message, you probably need to study the R code to see what went wrong.